# How to save image when two bounding box touching

Tags: python, opencv

How can I save images when two boxes touch each other, I want when the bounding box faces touch the cigarette bounding box, the image will be saved as a whole.

This is the code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cigarette = cv2.CascadeClassifier('classifier/cigarette-cascade.xml')
faced = cv2.CascadeClassifier('classifier/face-detect.xml')

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, img = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faced.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    cigarettes = cigarette.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for x,y,w,h in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    for (x, y, w, h) in cigarettes:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('test', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: you can use (RectA & RectB).area() to find out if the two regions intersect

Comment: Can you give me example?

Answer (score 0):

you can check point coordinate if in another box or not:

```
cnt=0
for x,y,w,h in faces:
    for x_,y_,w_,h_ in cigarettes:
        if not len(set(range(x,x+w))&set(range(x_,x_+w_)))==0 and \
            not len(set(range(y,y+h))&set(range(y_,y_+h_)))==0:
            cnt +=1
            cv2.imwrite("save_%s.jpg"%cnt, img)
```

Comment: Can you explain to me how ```if x in range(x_,w_)``` work?